# Date Conversion in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, date-conversion

I have Date in format as Date

> 1/24/2019 2:10:14 AM

Power BI read it as text. I want to convert it as

> 1-24-2019 2:10:14 AM

in single cell Date format.

I tried split, works but it change the format to

> 24/1/2019 2:10:14

& I also need AM which I was unable to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try 
FORMAT(datecolumn , "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss am/pm")

Comment: HI, Thks. But still post passing this syntax, data type is "text". Data type should be "date" right?

Comment: Hi Kshitij - you should be able to change the data type to date time in edit queries - change type -  then create another column and pass the given the column